Image of the Squaring Function on $ \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Q}) $
Find the image of the function
$
f : \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Q}) \to \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Q}), \quad f(X) = X^2, \quad \forall X \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Q}).
$
I can’t find the correct approach for this problem.
Here is what I have tried so far:
Let
$$
   X = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
   $$
where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then,
$$
   Y = X^2 = \begin{pmatrix} a^2 + bc & b(a + d) \\ c(a + d) & bc + d^2 \end{pmatrix}.
   $$
$$
     \text{tr}(Y) = a^2 + bc + bc + d^2 = a^2 + d^2 + 2bc.
     $$
Notice that $a + d$ is the trace of $X$, denoted $t$, and $\det(X) = ad - bc = s$. Using these,
$$
 \text{tr}(Y) = t^2 - 2s.
 $$
$$
 \det(Y) = (a^2 + bc)(bc + d^2) - (b(a + d))(c(a + d)) = (a^2 + d^2 + 2bc)(ad - bc) = (t^2 - 2s)s = s^2.
 $$
Since $\det(Y) = s^2$, $\det(Y)$ must be a perfect square in $\mathbb{Q}$.
From
$$
 \text{tr}(Y) = t^2 - 2s,
 $$
for some $t \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have:
$$
 t^2 = \text{tr}(Y) + 2s.
 $$
Given $s = \pm \sqrt{\det(Y)}$, this implies that
$$
 \text{tr}(Y) \pm 2\sqrt{\det(Y)}
 $$
must be a perfect square in $\mathbb{Q}$.
Combining the above, a matrix $Y \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is in the image of $f$ if and only if:
$\det(Y)$ is a perfect square in $\mathbb{Q}$. Additionally, there exists a rational number $t$ such that
$$
   \text{tr}(Y) = t^2 - 2\sqrt{\det(Y)}
   $$
or
$$
   \text{tr}(Y) = t^2 + 2\sqrt{\det(Y)}.
   $$
I got stuck from here. Any help is appreciated it.

The initial argument follows from multiplicativity of the determinant: $det(X^2)=det(X)^2$ is a perfect square in $\mathbb{Q}$.

By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $X^2 = \text{tr}(X)X - \det(X)I$. If we take the trace on both sides, we see that
$$
\text{tr}(X^2) = \text{tr}(X)^2 - 2\det(X),
$$
which is what you found
